# Having adding to dictionary problems python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is part of my code:

```
add_values=[2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000,20000,50000]
for each in add_values:
    print(each)
    s=add_values[each]
    s=int(s)
    h=s*100
    mydict[add_values[each]]=s
```

And it is bringing up this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range 
(For the s=add_values[each] line)
```

Please can you tell what is wrong here and what needs changing,

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect `add_values[each]` to be?

Answer (score 1):

Think about reaching the fifth item in `add_values`:

```
for each in add_values: 
    print(each) # each == 50
    s=add_values[each] # what's the fiftieth item in 'add_values'?!
```

You don't need to index into `add_values`, you are already accessing the value - replace `add_values[each]` with, simply, `each`.

Answer (score 0):

`each` is the value, you can't use it as an index (mainly because the size of `add_values` is 14 and you have values that are greater than this inside `add_values`):

```
add_values=[2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000,20000,50000]
for each in add_values:
    print(each)
    s=each
    s=int(s)
    h=s*100
    mydict[each]=s
```

Another solution would be to use an index:

```
add_values=[2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000,20000,50000]
for i in range(len(add_values)):
    print(add_values[i])
    s=add_values[i]
    s=int(s)
    h=s*100
    mydict[add_values[i]]=s
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an array *element* as an array *index*, which is why you are getting an out-of-bounds error.

With Python's `for` loop notation, you don't need to access an index explicitly; just access the element, which in your case is `each`:

```
for each in add_values:
    print(each)
    s=each              # kind of redundant, but this should work
```

Answer (score 0):

`for each in add_value` sets `each` to 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, etc.  On the 4th iteration of the loop, `each` is 20.  When you say `add_values[each]`, you get an error because `add_values` has only 14 elements and you're trying to access element number 20.  You'd get in even more trouble if it tried to access element number 50000.